# How to change the label of the choiceType input field?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on symfony2.8 and am trying to display the Label of the choiceType(radiobutton) as desired(not the one guessed by doctrine from the variable used to store the input data eg. eT1 or eT2) . Is there a syntax for for that or do i necessarily need to change the variable name to the name i want to display eg. event1 or event2. Moreover what if i want to display "Please select event for time slot 1" instead of just event1?

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use AppBundle\Entity\events;
    //use AppBundle\Entity\eventtype;
    use AppBundle\Entity\users;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

    class DefaultController extends Controller {

        /**
         * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
         */
        public function indexAction(Request $request) {
            $events = new events();

            $form = $this->createFormBuilder($events)
                    ->add('eT1', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'Poker' => 1,
                            'Chess' => 2,
                            'Cricket' => 3,
                            'Marbles' => 4,
                            'Football' => 5,
                        ),
                        'choices_as_values' => true,
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false, 
                    ))
                    ->add('eT2', ChoiceType::class, array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'Poker' => 1,
                            'Chess' => 2,
                            'Cricket' => 3,
                            'Marbles' => 4,
                            'Football' => 5,
                        ),
                        'choices_as_values' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        ))
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'))
                    ->getForm();

            if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
                $form->submit($request);

                if ($form->isValid()) {
                    // perform some action, eg. persisting the data to database...
                    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
                    $events->setuser($user);
    //               var_dump($id);
    //                exit;
                    //$events->setuserID($id);


                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                    // tells Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
                    $em->persist($events);

                    // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
                    $em->flush();
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
                }
            }

            return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                        'form' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        }
    }
```

Below is the events entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * events
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="events")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\eventsRepository")
 */
class events {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $user_id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ET1", type="integer")
     */
    protected $eT1;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ET2", type="integer")
     */
    protected $eT2;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="users", inversedBy="multievents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $singleUser;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get user_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getuser_id() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param integer $user
     * @return events
     */
    public function setUser($user) {
        $this->singleUser = $user;
    }


    /**
     * Set eT1
     *
     * @param integer $eT1
     * @return events
     */
    public function setET1($eT1) {
        $this->eT1 = $eT1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eT1
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getET1() {
        return $this->eT1;
    }

    /**
     * Set eT2
     *
     * @param integer $eT2
     * @return events
     */
    public function setET2($eT2) {
        $this->eT2 = $eT2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eT2
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getET2() {
        return $this->eT2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just set the [`label`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#label) through the `ChoiceType` options?

Comment: Did you try the option "choice_label"?

Comment: @kingkero  I tried {{ form_label(form.name, 'Choose Event') }} in the twig file as recommended in http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded

gives error - Method "name" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in default/index.html.twig at line 6

Comment: @Letsrocks  The choice_label option as described in the Symfony.com documentation says it is used to modify the display name of the options. Nothing mentioned as to how to change the label of the entire list. By default the label is "guessed" from the field name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following symfony documentation you can read [HERE](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#label) that in case to do that:

**type**: *string* **default**: The label is "guessed" from the ***field name***

Sets the label that will be used when rendering the field. Setting to false will suppress the label. The label can also be directly set inside the template:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your name') }}
```

Comment: I tried {{ form_label(form.name, 'Choose Event') }} in the twig file as recommended in symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/… gives error - Method "name" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in default/index.html.twig at line 6

Comment: I added 'label' => 'Choose Event', into the controller itself. Is now working fine. Thank you :)